# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. New problem

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I  am getting this error can anyone help me how can I fix it so I can build the apk. So far I have changed from gradle to internal but still no fix. Also I am using unity 2018.3.0f3. i have read many post but still I was not able to solve it.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.0f2/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/OpenJDK/MacOS/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.0f2/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':IronSource:verifyReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  Output:  /Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/IronSource/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml:146: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka com.Company.ProductName:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.

  Command: /Users/ompatel/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/d7ea5946da9faffe0caa1c17db8db060/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/ompatel/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/IronSource/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /var/folders/sp/kjxv1v1s3jbgn7c1qydkgc9m0000gn/T/aapt-6683475634438936978-out\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --non-final-ids\
          -0\
          apk\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
]
stdout[
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
:checkReleaseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
:IronSource:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:IronSource:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:IronSource:checkReleaseManifest
:IronSource:processReleaseManifest
:OneSignalConfig:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OneSignalConfig:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OneSignalConfig:checkReleaseManifest
:OneSignalConfig:processReleaseManifest
:sdkbox_review_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdkbox_review_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:sdkbox_review_lib:checkReleaseManifest
:sdkbox_review_lib:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:IronSource:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:OneSignalConfig:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:sdkbox_review_lib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:IronSource:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:OneSignalConfig:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:sdkbox_review_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
:IronSource:compileReleaseRenderscript
:IronSource:generateReleaseResValues
:IronSource:generateReleaseResources
:IronSource:packageReleaseResources
:OneSignalConfig:compileReleaseRenderscript
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseResValues
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseResources
:OneSignalConfig:packageReleaseResources
:sdkbox_review_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseResValues
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseResources
:sdkbox_review_lib:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseRFile
:IronSource:generateReleaseRFile
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseRFile
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseRFile
:processReleaseResources
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:82: warn: duplicate definitions of 'C2D_MESSAGE', overriding previous.

:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:IronSource:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:IronSource:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:IronSource:generateReleaseSources
:IronSource:javaPreCompileRelease
:IronSource:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:IronSource:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:IronSource:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:OneSignalConfig:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseSources
:OneSignalConfig:javaPreCompileRelease
:OneSignalConfig:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:OneSignalConfig:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:OneSignalConfig:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:sdkbox_review_lib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseSources
:sdkbox_review_lib:javaPreCompileRelease
:sdkbox_review_lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:sdkbox_review_lib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:sdkbox_review_lib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseAssets
:IronSource:mergeReleaseShaders
:IronSource:compileReleaseShaders
:IronSource:generateReleaseAssets
:IronSource:packageReleaseAssets
:OneSignalConfig:mergeReleaseShaders
:OneSignalConfig:compileReleaseShaders
:OneSignalConfig:generateReleaseAssets
:OneSignalConfig:packageReleaseAssets
:sdkbox_review_lib:mergeReleaseShaders
:sdkbox_review_lib:compileReleaseShaders
:sdkbox_review_lib:generateReleaseAssets
:sdkbox_review_lib:packageReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/libs/CustomActivity.jar: D8: Type `com.sdkbox.plugin.SDKBox` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.sdkbox.activity.CustomActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)`
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener.onTokenRefresh()`
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/libs/AF-Android-SDK.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener.onTokenRefresh()`
/Users/ompatel/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-12.0.1.aar/b77eb6893d26feb2ecf9a70f54c0c6f0/jars/classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.zzde(android.content.Context)`
/Users/ompatel/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-12.0.1.aar/b77eb6893d26feb2ecf9a70f54c0c6f0/jars/classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzde(android.content.Context)`
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/sdkbox_review_lib/libs/PluginReview.jar: D8: Type `com.sdkbox.plugin.SDKBox` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.sdkbox.plugin.PluginReview$1.run()`
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/sdkbox_review_lib/libs/PluginReview.jar: D8: Type `com.sdkbox.plugin.SDKBox` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.sdkbox.plugin.PluginReviewListener.onNegativeBtnClicked()`
/Users/ompatel/Desktop/Unity Games Zips/1010 ironsource update/1010 ironsource update/Temp/gradleOut/sdkbox_review_lib/libs/PluginReview.jar: D8: Interface `com.sdkbox.plugin.PluginListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.sdkbox.plugin.PluginReview` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease
:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:IronSource:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:IronSource:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:IronSource:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:IronSource:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:OneSignalConfig:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:OneSignalConfig:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:OneSignalConfig:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:OneSignalConfig:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:sdkbox_review_lib:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:sdkbox_review_lib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:sdkbox_review_lib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:sdkbox_review_lib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:checkReleaseLibraries UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
:packageRelease
:assembleRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:extractReleaseAnnotations
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleReleaseAar
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:verifyReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:assembleRelease
:IronSource:extractReleaseAnnotations
:IronSource:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:IronSource:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:IronSource:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:IronSource:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:IronSource:bundleReleaseAar
:IronSource:compileReleaseSources
:IronSource:mergeReleaseResources
:IronSource:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
112 actionable tasks: 88 executed, 24 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Running into the same issue. Contacting IronSource. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? @Bodman did you find a solution?

Comment: Look at @Đuro Kliček answer

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the sdk version ur using.

Go to control panel and unintall the current android sdk tool then.

Go to Edit/user preferences inside unity and then select sdk and download from there and install it.

It should work then i guess. It worked for me though.

Comment: i still get same error but now i get it about the jdk

Comment: Uninstall jdk and then dowbload from user preference and then install and then tell me if it work. If it doesn't work i will tell u which version of jdk to install.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the IronSource unity plugin. There should be an AndroidManifest.xml in Assets/Plugins/android/ironSource, remove this part:

```
...
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...
```

It also looks like the IronSource Unity plugin AndroidManifest.xml and AndroidManifest.xml from play-services-basement.aar, which IronSource has a dependency to, both have those same lines and they collide.

I contacted IronSource support because I had the same problem. They got back to me and said that I should remove those lines. Also that they will remove those lines from the plugin in the next release.